# Fazer override do decorator do Python mock

Tags: python, testes, mock

Eu tenho uma classe `TestCase` onde todos os testes, menos um, precisam fazer o mesmo patch de um objeto. Eu estou usando o [Python Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/), e fiz o seguinte:

```py
@mock.patch('metodo_alvo', mock.Mock(return_value=1))
class Tests(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('metodo_alvo', mock.Mock(return_value=2))
    def test_override(self):
        (....)
```

A idéia é que o decorator em `test_override` "sobrescrevesse" o patch feito na classe, mas não está funcionando. Quando eu rodo os testes, `metodo_alvo` recebe o patch da classe.

Depois de muito debug, eu descobri que quando o python constroi a suíte de testes, o decorator em `test_override` (o método) é chamado **antes** do decorator em `Tests` (a classe), e como o `mock` aplica os patches nessa ordem, o decorator da classe sobrescreve o comportamento do decorator do método.

Isso tá certo? Eu esperava o contrário, e agora não tenho certeza de como fazer override de um patch na classe. Talvez usar `with`?

Answer (score 4):

[A explicação do mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1764/fazer-override-do-decorator-do-python-mock/1766#1766) sobre a ordem de aplicação dos decorators faz sentido. Da mesma forma como uma pilha de decoradores é aplicada de baixo para cima. Eu é que esperava o contrário, por algum motivo.

Mas de qualquer forma, depois de pensar sobre mocking (sou novato no assunto ainda) eu percebi que não faz o menor sentido tentar aplicar um novo patch sobre um objeto que já foi mockado. Se ele já foi mockado, então eu posso fazer o que eu quizer com ele, o que abre um leque de possibilidades! Primeiro eu tentei:

```python
@mock.patch('metodo_alvo', mock.Mock(return_value=1))
class Tests(TestCase):

    def test_override(self):
         metodo_alvo.return_value = 2
         (....)
```

Funcionou como eu queria, mas teve o efeito colateral de alterar o valor do `metodo_alvo` permanentemente, para todos os casos de teste subsequentes. Então, obviamente, eu tentei:

```python
@mock.patch('metodo_alvo', mock.Mock(return_value=1))
class Tests(TestCase):

    def test_override(self):
         metodo_alvo.return_value = 2
         (....)
         metodo_alvo.return_value = 1
```

E aí sim tudo funcionou perfeitamente, mas tem uma baita cara de gambiarra. E o Python tem uma gerência de contexto que funciona muito bem nessa situação, e para a qual o Mock dá suporte:

```python
@mock.patch('metodo_alvo', mock.Mock(return_value=1))
class Tests(TestCase):

    def test_override(self):
         with mock.patch('metodo_alvo', mock.Mock(return_value=2):
             (....)
```

Faz a mesma coisa que eu tentei com a sobrescrita do decorator, mas agora em tempo de execução do método. Funcionou perfeitamente, é claro e conciso.

Answer (score 2):

Isso está correto, sim. Para que a classe seja passada para o decorador, é necessário que ela já esteja construída - o que signifia que seus campos e métodos já têm que estar prontos e atribuídos. Desse modo, o decorador do método já terá sido executado:

```python
>>> def decorador(x):
...   print 'decorando ' + str(x)
...   return x
...
>>> @decorador
... class Foo(object):
...   @decorador
...   def bar():
...     pass
...
decorando <function bar at 0x00C7C2F0>
decorando <class '__main__.Foo'>
```

A solução mais simples que posso propor [se esse patch está sobrescrevendo a si próprio] é você atribuir o método particular só depois de já ter criado a classe:

```python
@mock.patch('metodo_alvo', mock.Mock(return_value=1))
class Tests(TestCase):
    ...

@mock.patch('metodo_alvo', mock.Mock(return_value=2))
def test_override(self):
    (....)

Tests.test_override = test_override
```

Uma alternativa, caso isso não funcione por qualquer motivo (não conheço o Python Mock), seria você criar o seu próprio decorador que "marcasse" o método no qual ele é aplicado, e não aplicasse novamente na hora de aplicá-lo à classe:

```python
from types import FunctionType

def meu_patch(f, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(f, FunctionType):
        ret = mock.patch(f, *args, **kwargs) # Aplica o patch ao método
        ret.__marcado__ = True               # Marca-o, para que o patch não seja reaplicado
        return ret
    elif isinstance(f, type):
        for k,v in f.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(v, FunctionType) and not getattr(v, '__marcado__', False):
                f[k] = mock.patch(v, *args, **kwargs) # Aplica o patch aos métodos que não
                                                      # foram previamente aplicados
    return f
```

(nota: talvez essa "marcação" seja desnecessária, caso o resultado de uma aplicação prévia do `patch` tenha alguma característica distinta; seria o resultado **sempre** do tipo `MagicMock`? Se sim, basta testar isso, em vez de usar um atributo extra.)

Uma última alternativa seria usar metaclasses, mas não creio que traria qualquer benefício em relação aos métodos anteriores - só mais complexidade.